# Using ANT to migrate picklist updates

Tags: deployment, picklist, ant

I have a picklist with 3 values: A, B, D.

In my Sandbox X, I edited 'D' to be 'C' both value and label. This made all existing records using 'D' to now show 'C'.

When I deployed the picklist from Sandbox X to Dev Sandbox Y using ANT, it created a new value 'C' in the picklist and deactivated 'D'.

But now all the records using 'D' as the value remain 'D' instead of being 'C'. Am i going to have to run a replace job post deployment or is there a way ANT can do this during the deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this during deployment, but you also don't need to "run a job" to fix everything. Just go in to the field's definition, click on Del to remove the inactive value, and after confirming you want to do this, on the next screen, you'll be given a chance to replace all the D with the new C. You can also use the Replace feature to replace the values after removing the value, as well.